# DocuSign Autoplace text not working when using API integration / Power Automate query

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I have 2 queries based on the following :

I recently followed this DocuSign article to pass a supplied document to Docusign via the API:

https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate?_ga=2.99447774.1174083755.1646148960-1179341585.1645460870

**Query 1** - This all works apart from the AutoPlace text just isn't getting picked up. I added the variables as described in the article and referenced them in the document footer. The document is passed through the API call and the invitation to sign goes out ok. Is there anything I'm missing here? I can open the document for signing but docusign doesn't go to the places where the AutoPlace tags are, just leaves it open for the user to decide what to do. I've previously tried using AutoPlace using templates, but this is a document that will be sent through the API as it is provided by our users (with the correct AutoPlace intact). The article hints this should just work.

Update : this is now working but need advice on text color

[signing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPVro.png)

Update : Showing white signature on black background

[white signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANvaY.png)

**Query 2** - Once the user has signed the document using the above, I want to trigger a power automate flow off. There is a trigger for this but when I try to form the connection to DocuSign, there is only a login for the main account, not the developer account. So the account where I've made the account from isn't the one where I can fire off the triggers from. This makes it impossible to then fire a flow when it has been sent to the API and subsequently signed. Is there a way to use the trigger using the same account as the API account? If not it seems a bit crazy that I can start the process using the API but then can't fire flows from the result of the signings.

We have a company account ( I'm working on behalf of Transport for Wales) but was told there is no API support at all, which also sounds a bit bizarre. Hoping someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 - there's an AutoPlace settings that determine the scope - document/envelope for AutoPlace. You may want to see if the issue happens also when you use the web app and not from API - if the same challenge - then you need to contact support to change this scope. If not, it may mean you're not setting your `templateRole` correctly. It must match the same one that was defined on the template (case sensitive).

Query 2 - no, the OTB connector is production only. For the developer account you will need to use a custom connector for any REST API, not the one provided for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying and getting back to me quick.

For Query 1, I've followed the guide I linked in and don't have a template setup in DocuSign. These are simply documents sent across via the custom connector API call (as per the guide) that have matching tags "\s1\" in my footer and "\s1\" defined as a document custom field in the developer centre (also tried "\s{r}\" as per the guide but no different). Do I need a template uploading and "matching" as such or should this just work? The guide doesn't explain to do anything else

Comment: Update, I've fiddled about with this a lot and it just started working. I've updated my main question with how it looks now, can users sign in white text rather than black? We can do this using text (see "Director" on the screenshot) but the signature isn't easy to see on a black background

Comment: I'm checking on this, but black background is not usually something we see, so you may not have a good/simple solution. I'll let you know what I find, but please consider if you can change to white background

Comment: thanks for checking, it's really odd that different colours wouldn't be an option on signing. When you login to e-signature, the example signature is literally white on a black background too!

See my original post for a image

Comment: https://account-d.docusign.com/me/signatures allows you to upload your own signature. You can upload a black one if you want.